# Reading from mysql table issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm dealing with strange problem.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT link FROM item WHERE item_id='$id2'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$picture = ''.$row['link'].'';
echo"$picture";
```

Gives me result `http://127.0.0.1/1321426277.` without ending, while in column `link` link is: `http://127.0.0.1/1321426277.jpg`. Why it cuts ending?

Comment: all those quotes in the last 2 lines essentially do nothing...you know that right?

Comment: check the length of 'link' column into database, as well the datatype should be a varchar

Comment: I'm not sure to get it, why would you want to do that `$picture = ''.$row['link'].''; echo "$picture"`, isn't that much more simple : `echo $row['link']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing purposes please run

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT link, Length(link) as l FROM item WHERE item_id='$id2'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ( !$row ) {
  echo 'no such record';
}
else {
  $l = strlen($row['link']);
  var_dump($l, $row['l'], $row['link']);

  $picture = $row['link'];
  echo "'$picture'";
}
```

and post the result.

Comment: the result is: `int(0) string(2) "42" string(42) "http://127.0.0.1/baldai/akcija/1321428326." 'http://127.0.0.1/baldai/akcija/1321428326.'`

Comment: I somehow doubt at least the `int(0)` part. But anyway, the mysql server also "thinks" that the string is 42 characters long and `http://127.0.0.1/baldai/akcija/1321428326.` are 42 characters. The problem is not in your php script. How do you know "while in column `link` link is: `http://127.0.0.1/1321426277.jpg`"? And check jogesh_p`s comment.

Comment: I'm using it in other place: `<?php echo '<img src="'.$row['link'].'" width="200" height="117"/>' ?>` and it is working, so I'm sure that everything is ok with mysql table. I thought that I'm too "blond" to see something obvious, but now i even don't know what to think.

Comment: Are you sure it's working in the other place you mention? Are you sure it's not just outputting 1321428326. and the server is using content negotiation to display the image?

Comment: Have you quadruple-checked that you pull the exact "same" records from the exact same source? I.e. same server, same database, same table, same id?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your code that would cause the link to be truncated. Have you checked to make sure you have the correct data in your table?

Comment: Neither do I! Yes, data is correct, in fact I'm using it in other place `<?php echo '<img src="'.$row['link'].'" width="200" height="117"/>' ?>`and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in the data. Print out (and select) the ID at both places (the query in your question and the other place where you use it in *img src* tag). I bet they will differ. Or, you should check **SELECT count(1) FROM item WHERE item_id='xxx'***, where xxx is the ID of the magic record.

Answer (score 0):

Ah now I see = the problem is because you code contains an 'r' after the 'o' rather then before - it is so clear now because you provided such a complete example of the behavior that I replicate on my machine.

WTF